# Place HTML content in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Hi, how do I place a HTML page in NodeJs which is in another location?**
Here is w3school method however both pages must be in same location: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp

Thanks

**EDIT: PLEASE SEE ANSWER AT THE BOTTOM, I HAVE MANAGED TO SOLVE THE ISSUE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
const http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')
const hostname = '127.0.0.1'
const port = 8080
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
fs.readFile('Demo.html', function(err, data) { //HERE PLACE YOUR HTML FILE
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
res.write(data)
return res.end()})})
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {console.log(`Server running at 
http://${hostname}:${port}/`)})
```